# ftp quote site list of available options- Execute commands

Tags: unix, ftp, command, execute, mainframe

I was looking for list of available options for ftp quote site which will allow to do lot of stuff like executing commands on the target system. Like the below one can be used to submit jobs on mainframes.

```
quote site filetype=jes
put filetoexecute.jcl
```

I know that there are similar options for unix environment as well. Is there any list of available options for this quote command for unix, mainframes (windows also if available) environments.

Also below is an extra question based on these.
Is there any way to execute ca7 commands from this ftp? If not I was looking into one rexx example which will execute the ca7 commands passed as arguments. But this is failing with "CA-7 RECEIVER NOT FOUND" error.

```
PARSE UPPER ARG COMMAND  
ADDRESS CA7 COMMAND      
SAY 'RC=' RC             
X=QUEUED()               
SAY 'QUEUED() =' X       
DO I=1 TO X              
   PULL LINE             
   LINE2=SUBSTR(LINE,2)  
   SAY LINE2             
END
```

Also the below command is failing with the same failure.

```
ADDRESS CA7 "'LQ,SEQ=JOB,JOB=*'"
```

I have checked ca7 manual and don't know how to make sure that CA7 environment is configured to execute the above commands.
Can you please help?

Comment: I gave up the idea of executing CA7 commands from ftp and started submitting a JCL job which will communicate with CA7 through SASSBSTR
.

Answer (score 0):

The IBM FTP server supports HELP SITE; this gives you all of the operands that the SITE command supports. You can issue STAT to get the current SITE values.

This is specific to the IBM FTP server. Each FTP server is different, and they may or may not implement the SITE command. I suggest looking at the doc for the FTP server to find if they support SITE and STAT, or similar.